# Mutate a character column with a decimal point to a numeric

Tags: r, dplyr

I think this is a rather simple question which nevertheless frustrates me very much because all my attempts do not work:

I have a dataset(df) where an important column is defined as a character. To make matters worse, the numbers are represented with a comma, although all decimal places are 0.

| Product | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 12333 | 5,0 |
| 12333 | 1,0 |

What I tried:

`mutate(df$Amount = as.numeric(df,Amount))`

Which gave me an error
(Error: unexpected(s) '=' in "mutate(df$Amount =")

I also tried
`as.numeric(df$Amount)`

Which gave me a warning (NAs created by conversion) and thus created only NAs

Can someone please explain to me where I made a mistake and how I can do it the right way?

In addition: I joined Stackoverflow recently, so if I asked the question wrong or didn't provide valueable informations to my problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
library(stringr)
x <- c('5', '5.0', '5,0')
as.numeric(str_replace(x, ',', '.'))
```

which gives:

[1] 5 5 5

In your case:

```
df$Amount <- as.numeric(str_replace(df$Amount, ',', '.'))
```

Your problem was that you have a comma as decimal point but it needs to be a point.

Comment: Thank you, your solution worked like a charm!
In addition, it's really great to gain knowledge about the stringr package!